# Why TreeView.NodeMouseHover event occurs only when the mouse hovers over TreeNode's text area?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, treeview

The problem is that NodeMouseHover event occurs only when the mouse hovers over node's text area, but I have treeview with full row select like this:

[image]

What event should I use or how should I change NodeMouseHover, so event fires when mouse pointer hovers over the whole node but not only text area ?

Answer (score 1):

Just try MouseHover-Event and get the selected Item:

```
private void treeView1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TreeNode selNode =    (TreeNode)treeView1.GetNodeAt(treeView1.PointToClient(Cursor.Position));

    if (selNode != null)
    {
        // Do something...
    }
}
```

Comment: But `MouseHover` event fires only once, when cursor enters the control, in my case it's tree view, and stops in there, but when I move cursor to another node - nothing happens